# require_once in kohana3.3 showing the Server error

Tags: php, kohana-3.3

In kohana 3.3 i need to include one of the controller file in the another controller

I used `require_once( realpath(dirname(FILE) . '/Twitteroauth.php' ) );`

Its showing the server error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the file whether it exists or not?

Comment: ya its in controller folder only.. if i removed that, it showing the class Twitteroauth not found

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: `var_dump(realpath(dirname(FILE) . '/Twitteroauth.php' ));`

Comment: Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving myurl/user/share. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

Comment: if i user var_dump again it showing the Class 'Twitteroauth' not found

Comment: @mangala: `var_dump` would just output the full path, it cannot throw such an error.

Comment: @zerkms it showing that error only

Comment: @mangala: well, you need to contact a real developer or learn how to program then. Your error explanations aren't helpful.

Comment: What friend... i am really need helps...

Comment: @mangala: we all do, but it's REALLY difficult to help to a person who has no idea what they are doing. Try to contact to the person who developed the site originally. Or open php and kohana documentation and start learning it.

Comment: Ok thanks to every one.... i don how explain.... really thanks ur interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this:

```
require_once( realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Twitteroauth.php' ) );
```

Comment: it may be right, but just a side note: `realpath` makes no sense here

Comment: i did the same .. no use

Comment: yeah...realpath isn't required

Answer (score 0):

Function `realpath` returns `false` when file does not exist, so you should maybe check result before `require`:

```
$path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Twitteroauth.php' );
if(!empty($path))
    require_once($path);
else
    die("$path not found!");
```